# Using three data sets of different resolutions together for imaging

Tags: image-processing, reconstruction

I am new in this community. I hope the question I want to ask suits the people here.

Here, we are dealing with two-ring Positron Emission Tomography (PET) scanner (figure 1), also called Compton-PET, because the inner detector ring is optimized for Compton scattering of gamma rays. In PET, we inject radiopharmaceuticals into the patient's body. These radiopharmaceuticals are positron emitting radiotracers. Positron emits from the nucleus of the atom and gets annihilated with a nearby electron, producing two gamma photons of energy 511 keV travelling in the opposite direction. PET scanner is designed to detect these gamma rays in pairs. These detected events are used to create images of radiotracer distribution inside patient body. These images are used in cancer diagnosis, cardiology, neurology etc.

[image]

In the case of Compton-PET scanner (figure 1), the inner ring gives extra capability to acquire different kinds of events (figure 2). As explained previously, the task of a PET scanner is to acquire annihilation photons in pairs. Now, if the time resolution of the detector is not good enough, then in lots of cases one of the photon from pair will not get detected. Similar things can happen due to limited geometrical sensitivity of the scanner. Now, if we are using Compton-PET, if one of the photons gets scattered in the inner ring and gets absorbed in the outer ring, then those events also can be used for imaging. We term this data set as "Singles". And the events where both photons get detected are called "Doubles".

[image]

Now the mathematical approach of creating images from data sets is based on defining Poisson likelihood and then using the MLEM algorithm to maximize the likelihood. Images created from these data sets are of different resolutions. This is mainly because when for "Doubles", the annihilation point is on the line; for "Singles", it is on the surface of a cone (figure 2). Also, for "Singles", Doppler broadening degrades the image, which is not the case for "Doubles" data.

I wonder if we can combine these data sets to produce a "synergy" in the image. By synergy, we mean that the image resolution will be better than all three images created individually from each data set.

**Edit -
Here, I am making the question more specific. Yes, there have been efforts in [current literature](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6560/abb92e) to enhance the resolution of "Singles" data by accurately modelling various physics-based degrading factors and detector optimization. And I believe there is a real possibility in that direction.
On the other hand, my enquiry is simple (?) mathematically. I am humbled to know how I interweave (?) two sets of data - "Doubles" and "Singles" - in their raw form. I know I am running out of mathematics vocabulary. One idea, of course, is to visualize lines (of "Doubles" data) as cones (of "Singles" data) with zero apex angles. In that case, I can develop an algorithm for cones and consider line data as a limiting case. But I want to approach the problem from a greater depth. I am not a mathematician, but we hear about "Data Integration" and "Data Fusion" a lot nowadays. Hence, as a physicist, as we always do, right now, I am trying to pick up a tool from mathematics which may give me the opportunity to approach the problem in a deeper way (?).
I hope I haven't confused you guys more. Let me know if you need any extra information.**

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Hello Satyajit Ghosh and welcome to Signal Processing SE. It could be beneficial to add some more information in your question. I am not an image processing guru but I believe that adding some more info on the kind and dimensionality of your data and mention what (if) you have tried so far could help people provide some educated (possible) answers.

Comment: yes! We rarely complain about too much background – as long as the question is well structured, which yours definitely is, adding more background usually makes it much easier to answer qualifiedly. So far, your question is far too vague and unspecific to be answerable (other than with "yes, probably. It depends"). We'd need to know how these images relate – are they of the same phenomenon, is orientation known, is noise correlated, is noise following the same stochastic models, is working on the images the right thing, or should we rather consider the signals that then get converted to images…

Comment: prefer to show rather than tell. information density is important.

Comment: Thank you @ZaellixA Have a look at the updated question. Specific questions you asked - (a) "more information on kind and dimensionality of your data" => data set "Doubles" is made of independent events where each event is defined by various information, e.g., positions of photon detection points on the detector, energies deposited by the photons, times when photons are detected; simply speaking each event form lines as you can see in figure 2 (left), many such line will be used to create image; (b) "what you have tried" => haven't done anything, just started literature review.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller . Have a look at the updated question. Your questions - (a) "are they of the same phenomenon" => yes; (b) "is orientation known" => i don't understand, but most probably yes; (c) "is noise correlated" => i don't think so; (d) "is noise ... same stochastic models" => no, of course not, for example "Singles" data contain Doppler broadening error which is not present in "Doubles"; (e) "is working on the images the ..... consider the signals that then get converted to images" => excellent question, better to work on the signal first to create some `low-level data fusion (?)'.

Comment: @SatyajitGhosh cool! That's harder than I thought, but good news, interesting! let me rephrase (a) then, though: If you observe an electron in the inner ring, it's not going to be detected by the outer ring, and vice versa, right?

Comment: @SatyajitGhosh Your question implies that you have access to the raw event data coming out of the scanner. Is this right? In any case, your question is still _too broad_ . And the equally broad answer is ["Yes, the two can be combined"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6560/abb92e) but there are a lot of details in the process of doing so. Can you make it a bit more specific?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am hoping you are talking about "Singles" data set. No, for these data definition of each event itself means same photon depositing a certain fraction of energy in the inner ring through Compton scattering and then depositing rest of its energy in the outer ring (figure 2). Then only we will able to create a cone (dotted cone shown in right side of figure 2) which is necessary for image reconstruction.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Now, if you mean "Doubles" data, then answer to your question will be yes. The reason is here we are considering the possibility of photoelectric absorption which means release of total energy. Hence it will get detected either in inner or in outer ring. The reason I have shown detection of these events in outer ring in figure 2 (left) is because outer ring is optimised for photoelectric absorption.

Comment: @A_A Thanks for the response. Yes, we have access to the raw event data of the scanner. Thanks for the paper. Let me read it. I will try modify the question and make it more specific as you asked.

Comment: @A_A Have a look in the edited question - the bold paragraph in the end. Thanks.

Comment: @SatyajitGhosh and all, I created a separate discussion in the chat about this question. I do think that it still needs to be clarrified further (or reach an agreement to close this particular one). Please see here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142586/on-using-three-datasets-of-different-resolutions